# How do I get a TextBox to fill a resizable column?

Tags: wpf, textbox, stretch, splitter

I'm trying to get a TextBox to fill the available space in a resizable column. The TextBox is part of a user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextBoxLayout.FieldControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0">Name</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This user control is in a window with a vertical splitter:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBoxLayout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxLayout"
    Title="Text box layout" Height="400" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:FieldControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Testing"/>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="Testing"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem is the TexTBox appears to be very narrow - what I'd want it to do is fill the left column and resize with the splitter. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean fit by width, or both width and heigth?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" instead of "Left" for FieldControl. Remove MaxWidth if required. Use TextAlignment to align text.

Comment: That works if I don't want to have a MaxWidth. However... if I add MaxWidth (because the column becomes very wide and I don't want the text field to fill it), then the FieldControl floats in the center of the column. If I add back HorizontalAlignment="Left", then I'm right back where I started. How do I get a text field to align to the left of a column without filling it, and cope with the column being shrunk when you drag the splitter?

Comment: I agree with imekon.  This answer puts you back to where you started.

Comment: @anivas +1 for distinction between HorizontalAlignment and TextAlignment, and the need to use both. I had forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to more examples for future code searches.

I put this in the top of the xaml file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="CenterCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Included, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then in the datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Excluded" Binding="{Binding Excluded}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CenterCell}"/>
```

This centers the text and sorting is still enabled. The textbox fills the cell and in this case is colored using a bool converter.

Answer (score 1):

just see whether is that you want

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <local:FieldControl Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Margin="2"
                         />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Testing" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Width="3" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               Text="Testing" />
</Grid>
```